# Can we also call them the reduced adverbial clauses?

Tags: terminology

https://www.grammaring.com/participle-clauses

> Tom lost his keys (while) walking through the park. (Tom lost his keys
> while he was walking through the park.)
>
> She left the room singing happily. (She left the room as she was
> singing happily.)

When I search "reduced adverbial clauses",  Sentences that start with a reduced adverbial clause are usually what I find in most of the English learning articles.(E.g., "After doing something, ..." , "Being late, ...")

The two sentences quoted above do not start with a reduced adverbial clause and they do not have a comma in each of them, and the article above even put a complete adverbial form of each sentence behind them. I wonder if their present participle parts are in fact a type of reduced adverbial clauses.

Comment: Like most adverbs, adverbial clauses, both reduced and unreduced, can appear in many places in a sentence, not just the beginning.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thank you. A lot of the articles only introduce few types of reduced adverbial clause and do not go into detail. Do you happen to know articles or books that may have more comprehensive content about reduced adverbial clause?

Comment: It's not a topic of particular interest except for those who are dogmatic about terminology. There are [many different syntactic rules](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf) that might apply to reduce clauses, and they are the usual objects of study. Adverbs and adverbial expressions are a wastebasket category in grammar, anyway; whatever someone can't explain is generally wished off to become an adverb. That's one reason why there are so many types of them.

Comment: @JohnLawler Great point. When I saw "based on" and "compared to" used in sentences like "The players get paid based on how far they advance" and "The cost was peanuts compared to a new kitchen", I always wondered what type of the grammatical terminology they were and now I guess they can be interpreted as the results of reduced adverbial clauses.

Comment: Among other things; those sentences have been done a lot of things to.

Comment: @JohnLawler I know this is off-topic, but the passive construction you used(_have been done a lot of things to_) in your comment seems unfamiliar to me. Could you briefly explain it? I'm quite curious.

Comment: Sure. It's produced by freezing the VP fragment _do a lot of things to_ and treating it as if it were a transitive verb with _this sentence_ as its object, then passivizing it. It's the sort of thing that happens with _that's being looked at, this bed has been slept in, they were kept tabs on_. Verb phrases can be parsed in multiple ways, and this is one of them. It's also an extreme example of the phenomenon, and an in-joke for syntacticians.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thank you. It's pretty interesting that the structure of _do a lot of things to_ is very similar to   _make a fool of_ and _keep tabs on_ but it will be the only one that sounds unnatural compared to the other two once they're passivized.

Comment: That's because the other ones are real idioms, while I just made one up and used it like it was an idiom. That's how they start.

Comment: @JohnLawler That's exactly what I thought. Although _do (a lot of)things/something to_ is a common usage it's still not an idiom. You are a very approachable grammarian and it's been great talking to you.